# Python abbreviated string record

Tags: python

Can anyone explain to me how another way to write ans.
I don't know how it works written in one line.

```
X = int(raw_input())
Y = int(raw_input())
Z = int(raw_input())
N = int(raw_input())
ans = [[i, j, k] for i in range(X + 1) for j in range(Y + 1) for k in range(Z + 1) if i + j + k != N]
print ans
```

Comment: look up list comprehensions

Comment: @PedjaMirkovic Which part don't you understand?

Comment: You want is in one line? `print([[i, j, k] for i in range(int(input()) + 1) for j in range(int(input() + 1) for k in range(int(input() + 1) if i + j + k != int(input()])`? (translated into python 3)

Comment: @Sören ans = [[i, j, k] for i in range(X + 1) for j in range(Y + 1) for k in range(Z + 1) if i + j + k != N] 
how to write another way, normally

Comment: nested list comprehensions like this are never very readable IMO

Comment: @PedjaMirkovic Do you mean the way I wrote in the answer?

Comment: As a beginner you should not be investing time in learning Python 2. Those of us who still work in it do so because we have to support or migrate legacy code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you meant:

```
X = int(raw_input())
Y = int(raw_input())
Z = int(raw_input())
N = int(raw_input())
ans = []

for i in range(X + 1):
    for j in range(Y + 1):
        for k in range(Z + 1):
            if i + j + k != N:
                ans.append([i, j, k])
print ans
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong